# Jolt Spec for populating field based on value of another field

Tags: jolt

I want to populate my target JSON with a field based on value of another field.

e.g.

```
Input JSON:
[

{
"examUrl": "https://exam.test.com/page/1473161074",
"urlTypeName": "Spring URL"
},

{
"examUrl": "https://exam.test.com/page/12423222",
"urlTypeName": "Java URL"
},

]
```

Expected Output:

```
{

"ExamDashBoardURL" : "https://exam.test.com/page/1473161074"

}
```

In the above example, I will populate ExamDashBoardURL only if urlTypeName is "Spring URL".

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. It may be helpful for someone.

If anyone has better spec, please let me know

````
[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"*": {
"urlTypeId": {
"1": {
"@2": "domoDashboardLink"
}
}
}
}
},
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"domoDashboardLink": {
"examUrl": "&1"
}
}
}
]```
````